# Error when add an additional volume for the web app container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

Error when add an additional volume for the Ruby on Rails web app container

Hello, I'm programmming a containerized Rails app. Right now I'm doing the setup for the production environment.

My `docker-compose.production.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb"
    volumes:
      - .:/rails-lyrics-site
      - /rails-lyrics-site/node_modules
      - bundle:/usr/local/bundle
      - public-data:/rails-lyrics-site/public
      - log-data:/rails-lyrics-site/log
      - tmp-data:/rails-lyrics-site/tmp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    build:
      context: containers/nginx
    volumes:
      - public-data:/rails-lyrics-site/public
      - tmp-data:/rails-lyrics-site/tmp
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  bundle:
  public-data:
  log-data:
  tmp-data:
```

The problem is when I start with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml up`, I got the error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQLTu.png)

The problems will not occur when I remove the `tmp-data` volume from the web container. It seems that with this config, my tmp folder in the Rails source code is not being written into

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: The first error points to the missing file rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid, as if you were trying to remove an inexistent file: "No such file or directory @
rb_sysopen - tmp/pids/server.pid". Add a check like this: `if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi`

Comment: You don't seem to have included the actual error message in your question, just a link.  Can you [edit] the question to include the actual error (not a link and not an image)?  I might suggest you can delete _all_ of the `volumes:` from the `web` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my problems were I didn't public the volume in Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ruby:3.1.2

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -\
    && echo 'deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential postgresql-client yarn \
    curl dirmngr apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates

WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

COPY . /app
RUN mkdir -p tmp/sockets

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

VOLUME /app/public
VOLUME /app/tmp

CMD bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec puma -C config/puma/production.rb"
EXPOSE 3000
```

After adding

```
VOLUME /app/public
VOLUME /app/tmp
```

The above docker compose worked

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the `tmp/pids` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Create tmp/pids at first time u run the docker compose